# Is it redundant to use htmlspecialchars for input then use htmlentities on output?

Tags: php, xss

I was told that the output from my database was double-escaped based on the output such as `&amp;#039; &amp;quot; &amp;lt;`

So, is `htmlspecialchars($content_to_escape, ENT_QUOTES)` for insert, then `echo htmlentities($content_to_echo);` redundant?

Comment: you don't need to escape html when putting it into the db (minus the usual sql injection protections). escaping of this sort should only be done on OUTPUT, because the purpose (and type) of escaping used depends entirely on how the output will be consumed. e.g. there'd be exactly NO use in doing html escaping if the html will never be used in a way where it could be rendered as html.

Comment: If you're putting it into a database, you shouldn't be using `htmlspecialchars()` anyways.  You should be using PDO which will handle loading it correctly.  You'll still need to sanitize it on output.

Comment: I am using PDO, bind param. So don't escape into database, escape out.

Answer (score 1):

Store input inside your database as given.

Optionally, you can validate inputs server side to disallow certain characters. For example, for a street name you might only allow alphanumerics and the `-`, `<space>` and `'` characters.

However, to prevent XSS the focus should be on output encoding. Use the HTML encoding functions each time on output. Storing raw input in your DB makes things much simpler (and thus much more secure) when you need to output to another context (e.g. hex entity encoding for JavaScript, JSON encoding, etc).

Comment: I decided to go with htmlspecialchars($content, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); what do you think of that?